# Promotion of primitive types

Tags: java, types, casting, wrapper, primitive

I have a question about the promotion of primitive types in Java. As we can see in the following example, one of the methods does not compile due to an error of type mismatch. Each method returns the same value but in different types.

The version of primitive `long` method works without error while the version of wrapper class `Long` fails. This is because the `int` literal in the `return` statement will be first promoted to a broader primitive type (e.g. `long`) and then to the corresponding wrapper class `Integer` and so on. Since `Integer` is not a subclass of `Long` the compiler gives an error.

But why does the version of wrapper class `Byte` works without any error? What exactly does the compiler do at this point?

```
long getPrimitiveLong() {
    return 12; // valid
}

Long getWrapperLong() {
    return 12; // Error: type mismatch
}

Byte getWrapperByte() {
    return 12; // valid
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `return 12L;` for `getWrapperLong`? It seems to work for me.

Comment: Yes, it works with 12L or (long) 12.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version with `Byte` works through some compiler magic.

Unlike `long` numeric literals which can be constructed with a `L` suffix, e.g. `12L`, there is no such thing as a `byte` literal. That is why Java compiler treats numeric literals that fit in a byte as `byte` literals. Hence, `12` in your last example is considered a constant of type `byte`.

[Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf) offers a description of this conversion in section 5.2:

> A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used
>   if the type of the variable is:
>
> - `Byte` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `byte`.
> - `Short` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `short`.
> - `Character` and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type `char`.

Answer (score 4):

This is because Java allows 1 conversion or Autoboxing, not more.

Java can do all these:

```
int i = 5;
double d = i; // int to double
long l = i; // int to long
long l = d; // double to long
```

Or autobox:

```
Integer i = 5; // int to Integer
Double d = 5.0; // double to Double
Long l = 5L; // long to Long
```

Converting twice, say int to Double, gives Java a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

number like 12 consider as int by default by the compiler that is why the error

To fix that you can use casting for byte and place L after the value of long variable.

Read following post for more details

http://javaseeeedu.blogspot.com/2015/12/casting-part-1.html

Answer (score 0):

As a short answer - try to replace 12 with 128 (byte is in range -128 to 127).
It won't compile, right?
The outcome here is that the compiler knows about byte boundaries.

For the in-depth answer you can do a deep dive into OpenJDK.